# Traverse both incoming and outgoing relationship in Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am new at Neo4j but not to graphs and I have a specific problem I did not manage to solve with Cypher.

With this type of data:

[image: Data model]

I would like to be able in a single query to follow some incoming and some outgoing flow.

Example:

- Starting on "source"
- Follow all "A" relationships in the outgoing way
- Follow all "B" relationships in the incoming way

My problem is that Cypher only allows one single direction to be specified in the relationship pattern.

So I could do `(source)-[:A|:B*]->() or (source)<-[:A|:B*]-()`.
But I have no possibility to tell Cypher that I want to follow `-[:A]-> and <-[:B]-`.

By the way, I know that I could do `-[:A|:B]-` but this won't solve my problem because I don't want to follow `-[:B]->` and `<-[:A]-`.

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To express this in a single query would require a regular path query, which has been proposed to and [accepted to openCypher](https://github.com/thobe/openCypher/blob/rpq/cip/1.accepted/CIP2017-02-06-Path-Patterns.adoc), but it is not yet implemented.

I see two possible workarounds. I recreated your example with this command with a `Source` label for the source node:

```
CREATE (:Source)-[:A]->()-[:A]->()<-[:B]-()-[:A]->()
```

(1) Insert additional relationships that have the same direction:

```
MATCH (s)-[:B]->(t)
CREATE (s)<-[:B2]-(t)
```

And use this relationship for traversal:

```
MATCH p=(source)-[:A|:B2*]->()
RETURN p
```

(2) As you mentioned:

> By the way, I know that I could do -[:A|:B]- but this won't solve my problem because I don't want to follow -[:B]-> and <-[:A]-.

You could use this approach to first get potential path candidates and manually check the directions of the relationships afterwards. Of course, this is an expensive operation but you only have to calculate it on the candidates, a possibly small data set.

```
MATCH p=(source:Source)-[:A|:B*]-()
WITH p, nodes(p) AS nodes, relationships(p) AS rels
WHERE all(i IN range(0, size(rels) - 1) WHERE
  CASE type(rels[i]) 
    WHEN 'A' THEN startNode(rels[i]) = nodes[i]
    ELSE /* B */  startNode(rels[i]) = nodes[i+1]
  END)
RETURN p
```

Let's break down how this works:

- We store path candidates in `p` and use the [`nodes`](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/list/#functions-nodes) and [`relationships`](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/list/#functions-relationships) functions to extract the lists of nodes/relationships from it.
- We define a [`range`](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/list/#functions-range) of indexes for the relationships (e.g. from `0, 1, 2` if there are 3 relationships).
- To determine the direction of relationships, we use the [`startNode`](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/scalar/#functions-startnode) function. For example, if there is a relationship `r` between nodes `n1` to `n2`, the paths will like `<n1, r, n2>`. If `r` was traversed to in the outgoing direction, the `startNode(r)` will return `n1`, if it was traverse in the incoming direction, `startNode(r)` will return `n2`. The type of the relationship is checked with the [`type`](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/scalar/#functions-type) function and a [simple `CASE`](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/expressions/#syntax-simple-case) expression is used to differentiate between types.
- The `WHERE` clause uses the [`all`](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/predicate/#functions-all) predicate function to check whether all `:A` and `:B` relationships had the appropriate directions.

Comment: Thank you Gabor. I will go for the relation duplication whereas this is not recommanded.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively to @Gabor Szarnyas answer, I think you can achieve your goal using the APOC procedure [apoc.path.expand](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_expand).

Using this sample data set:

```
CREATE (:Source)-[:A]->()-[:A]->()<-[:B]-()-[:A]->()
```

And calling `apoc.path.expand`:

```
match (source:Source)
call apoc.path.expand(source,"A>|<B","",0,5) yield path
return path
```

You will get this path as output:

[image: Output]

The `apoc.path.expand` call starts from the `source` node following `-[:A]->` and `<-[:B]-` relationships.

Remember to install [APOC procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures) according to the version of Neo4j you are using. Take a look in the [version compatibility matrix](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_version_compatibility_matrix).